# Woorank not finding my Conversion Form and W3C error

Tags: seo, w3c

I've been analyzing my website through `Woorank` and i'm getting this error

> We could not find a Conversion Form on this page

even though I do have a contact form working perfectly on my page.

Also gives me this W3C error but when I check on the site says it's fine too.

[This is my site](https://www.woorank.com/en/review/gaianet.com.br)

Someone knows how do I fix this on woorank??

Comment: Woorank doesn't specify, just: "Invalid: 4 Errors, 3 Warning(s)". But when I test on w3c test  and validator.nu it passed http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=gaianet.com.br  and https://validator.nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fgaianet.com.br

Comment: @EloiseM I recently came across a website, which has similar functionality to a Woorank, also have additional functions. I have checked you website there and I didn't found any such error there. You can check it once from your end.. here is the link of the website http://woorankplus.com 
Hope it help you. You an contact the support as they are extremely fast people and can help you get your problem resolved..... :)